# Atualizar banco com dados do form sem refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Olá, estou fazendo um painel de controle de um placar, aonde tenho uma tela com todos os jogos da rodada e como os jogos já estão previamente cadastrados no banco, preciso fazer a atualização dos jogos conforme as rodadas forem ocorrendo.
Consegui passar o ID do jogo, porém os demais inputs com os resultados não.

PHP

```
<?php
while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
?>
    <form id="frmPlacar" method="post"> 
    <TABLE align="center">
        <TR>
            <TH rowspan="2">
                <INPUT type="checkbox" name="ids[]" id="ids" value="<?php echo $ln['id_placar'];?>">
            </TH>
            <TH>
                <INPUT type="text" name="time1" value="<?php echo $ln['nm_time1'];?>" placeholder="Time visitante" disabled>
            </TH>
            <TD>
                <INPUT type="text" name="placar1_1" value="<?php echo $ln['nr_placar1_1'];?>" placeholder="1&ordm; Q" maxlength="2">
            </TD>                                    
            <TD>
                <INPUT type="text" name="placar1_2" value="<?php echo $ln['nr_placar1_2'];?>" placeholder="2&ordm; Q" maxlength="2">
            </TD>                                    
            <TD>
                <INPUT type="text" name="placar1_3" value="<?php echo $ln['nr_placar1_3'];?>" placeholder="3&ordm; Q" maxlength="2">
            </TD>                                    
            <TD>
                <INPUT type="text" name="placar1_4" value="<?php echo $ln['nr_placar1_4'];?>" placeholder="4&ordm; Q" maxlength="2">
            </TD>                                    
            <TD>
               <INPUT type="text" name="placar1_o" value="<?php echo $ln['nr_placar1_o'];?>" placeholder="OT" maxlength="2">
            </TD> 
            <TD>
                <INPUT type="text" name="placar1_f[]" value="<?php echo $ln['nr_placar1_f'];?>" placeholder="FINAL" maxlength="2">
            </TD> 
            <TD>
                <INPUT type="text" name="campanha1" value="<?php echo $ln['nm_campanha1'];?>" placeholder="CAMPANHA" maxlength="7">
            </TD> 
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TH>
                <INPUT type="text" name="time2" value="<?php echo $ln['nm_time2'];?>" placeholder="Time mandante" disabled>
            </TH>
            <TD>
                <INPUT type="text" name="placar2_1" value="<?php echo $ln['nr_placar2_1'];?>" placeholder="1&ordm; Q" maxlength="2">
            </TD>                                    
            <TD>
                <INPUT type="text" name="placar2_2" value="<?php echo $ln['nr_placar2_2'];?>" placeholder="2&ordm; Q" maxlength="2">
            </TD>                                    
            <TD>
                <INPUT type="text" name="placar2_3" value="<?php echo $ln['nr_placar2_3'];?>" placeholder="3&ordm; Q" maxlength="2">
            </TD>                                    
            <TD>
                <INPUT type="text" name="placar2_4" value="<?php echo $ln['nr_placar2_4'];?>" placeholder="4&ordm; Q" maxlength="2">
            </TD>                                    
            <TD>
               <INPUT type="text" name="placar2_o" value="<?php echo $ln['nr_placar2_o'];?>" placeholder="OT" maxlength="2">
            </TD> 
            <TD>
                <INPUT type="text" name="placar2_f[]" value="<?php echo $ln['nr_placar2_f'];?>" placeholder="FINAL" maxlength="2">
            </TD> 
            <TD>
                <INPUT type="text" name="campanha2" value="<?php echo $ln['nm_campanha2'];?>" placeholder="CAMPANHA" maxlength="7">
            </TD> 
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD colspan="8" class="bt" align="right">
                <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $ln['id_placar'];?>" name="jogos[]" id="jogo">
                <button class="btn btn-small btn-success" id="botao"><i class="icon-thumbs-up icon-white"></i>Alterar</button>
            </TD> 
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD colspan="8" align="left">
                <div id="erro">Erro:</div>
                <div id="sucesso">Sucesso:</div>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#botao', function () {

        var Jogo = new Array();

        $("input[name='ids[]']:checked").each(function(){
            Jogo.push(parseInt($(this).val()));
            alert(Jogo);
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "teste.php",
            data: "jogo="+Jogo,
            success: function(html){
                if(html=='true')
                {
                    $("#erro").html("");
                    $("#sucesso").html("Placar atualizado com sucesso!");
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#erro").html(html);
                    $("#sucesso").html("");
                }
            },
            beforeSend:function()
            {
                $("#erro").html("");
                $("#sucesso").html("");
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
})
```

Comment: Ricardo a resposta em baixo resolveu o teu problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é que você está a retirar o valor somente o valor do `input` cujo o `name=ids[]` e é se estiver `checked`.

O erro está nessa linha:

```
$("input[name='ids[]']:checked").each(function(){
   ...
```

Pode alterar para:

```
$('#frmPlacar input:checked').each(function(){
   ...
```

Assim já conseguirá o valor de todos os inputs que estão `checked`

Porque está a passar os valores como array para o servidor? Foi você trabalhou o ficheiro `teste.php`? Se foi e se me permite uma sugestão, eu sugeria que passa-se como Objeto, como array pode não dar o resultado esperado:

Eu faria sem o array `Jogo`:

```
var dados = {};
$('#frmPlacar input:checked').each(function(){
    // aqui cada chave vai ser o 'name' do input
    dados[$(this).prop('name')] = $(this).val();
});

...
data: dados,
success: function(html){
   console.log(html);
   ...
```

test.php

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    print_r($_POST);
    // verificar consola para ver resposta, se resulta
    // depois para aceder a cada key vá pelo 'name' dos inputs, não esquecendo que alguns deles são arrays. ex:
    print_r($_POST['placar2_f']); 
}
```